# Clone LI from normal unsorted UL list to sortable list

Tags: jquery, list, append, clone, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an unsorted UL list displaying search results.  I want the user to be able to click their required LI and have the entire LI copy to a jQuery UI sortable list where they can order and sort after selecting the required amount of items.  The LI in question is formated with spans, images and a hidden field containing a JSON.

**HTML:**

```
<li onclick="cloneToSortable(this);"><img src="item.jpg"> <span>Result Name</span> <input type="hidden" name="0arr" value='{"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":"val3"}' /></li>
<li onclick="cloneToSortable(this);"><img src="item.jpg"> <span>Result Name</span> <input type="hidden" name="1arr" value='{"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":"val3"}' /></li>
<li onclick="cloneToSortable(this);"><img src="item.jpg"> <span>Result Name</span> <input type="hidden" name="2arr" value='{"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":"val3"}' /></li>
<li onclick="cloneToSortable(this);"><img src="item.jpg"> <span>Result Name</span> <input type="hidden" name="3arr" value='{"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":"val3"}' /></li>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function cloneToSortable(li)
{
    $('#itemSearchList ul li:eq('+$(li).index()+')').clone().appendTo('#sortable');
}
```

This gives me no error message but it also gives me nothing in the sortable list either.  Any ideas why??

Comment: Why that mess? Why not simply: `$(li).clone().appendTo('#sortable')`?

Comment: Can that be added as the answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(li).clone().appendTo('#sortable')
```

Was exactly what I needed for this problem